# Simplest way to count quadrature encoder counts

Tags: integrated-circuit, encoder

I need to count the pulses from a high-res quadrature encoder but the prohibitively high frequency means I can't use my main processor.

I looked into the HCTL-2022 IC which does exactly what I need, although the part now appears to be obsolete.

Are there any other chips which would serve as a suitable substitution? Alternatively, how would I implement a circuit to count the pulses?

Comment: What does "high frequency" mean to you?

Comment: And what is your main processor?  The actual algorithm to implement quadrature encoder counts is pretty small.

Comment: Some uC’s have (hardware) peripherals to handle QEI.

Comment: A PIC or other small auxiliary micro, programmed as a decoder that talks on SPI or I2C.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, high enough that it would block the processor from executing its other tasks.

Comment: That is not a useful bit of information, particularly because you haven't even told us what this "processor" is.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, it's the LPC1768, which although does include a QEI, the position register is not signed, and is therefore unsuitable for my needs.

Comment: "high enough" is not a number.  What is the max. pulse rate in Hz and the minimum pulse width in seconds?  Also, do you need bi-directional (up/down) counting, or up-only?

Comment: @AnalogKid, 50khz, not sure about the pulse width. Needs to be bi-directional.

Comment: People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your work and findings so far in considerable detail. Don't post information in comments, put it in the question. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract.

Comment: "...the position register is not signed..."  Eh?  Signed and unsigned are meaningless distinctions, as long as the register rolls over.  0x0000 - 1 = 0xffff, regardless of whether you happen to be interpreting the results as a signed -1, or an unsigned 65535.  Just write the right code.

Comment: @TimWescott, I was under the impression that the counter would just stay at its upper and lower limits. i.e. 0x0 - 1 = 0x0, and 0xffff + 1 = 0xffff. If the register does roll over, then that's something I could work with. However, how would the QEI (LPC1768) signal that a roll over has occurred so that I can perform the correct maths on my software counter?

Comment: Check the data sheet carefully.  It would take more logic, and lend less utility, to have the thing saturate so I would be vastly surprised if it doesn't roll over.  To see how rollover is signaled, check the data sheet.  If it doesn't say, then you have to monitor it -- basically you sample the decoder fast enough that it never moves by more than a quarter turn between samples, ever, and if your measured number jumps by more than a quarter turn, then you assume rollover.

Comment: @TimWescott, Just checked, and it does overflow!

Comment: With a little extra gating, the counter can be frozen at its max and min values.  I've done it in a CPLD using all normal gates, so discrete should be no problem.  BUT, it would be lower cost and less complex to use an 8-pin PIC as a dedicated encoder interface/counter and read the results over SPI or I2C.  Do you need a max/min flag?  Also, how often do you read the count?

Comment: @AnalogKid, Count is read 1000/sec. The LPC1768 doesn't appear to indicate when an overflow has occurred, which does complicate things.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with that chip but a quick scan of the datasheet shows that it has four external interrupts. All that should be required is to monitor, say, one of the encoder outputs with an interrupt pin and when triggered count up or down depending on the status of the other encoder output.

[image]

*Figure 1. Encoder signals and resultant count.*

```
Pseudo code
// Triggered by encoder output A
interrupt {
  if(B) {
    encoder--    // Encoder is running anti-clockwise.
  } else {
    encoder++    // Encoder is running clockwise.
  }
}
```

You make the encoder variable as many bits long as required for the accuracy you need.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, as far I understood from your comments you have a LPC1768 with QEI, but the real problem is that you want signed math. Well it's not a problem at all, you have just to define or parse the QEI output (let say 32 bit unsigned integer uint) to signed integer int.

You may do all the signed or unsigned math you want. If you subtract actual value in uint format with other uint, you get the uint result, which will give you always the same direction. For the sake of simplification, let we have a compass 0(360)-359 degrees. If you subtract 350-20 you get 330, but if you subtract 20-350 you get 30. The angle difference is always 30 degrees, but you get two different results.

Now suppose you do signed math, same angles 20 and -10, 20--10=30, -10-20=-30. You see, when using signed math, you always get the shortest distance and direction.

Same rules apply when using binary numbers: signed will always give you shortest path - so you don't have to care about roll-over with sign (direction, in which direction should I turn to reach the target with a shortest move).

I give you an advice: there is no roll over problem ever, try to use the calculator and you will understand.

Answer (score 0):

Many microcontrollers have hardware quadrature encoder support:

- Microchip PIC has the [QEI](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70208A.pdf)
- some NXP processors have a [QEI](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/LPC1759_58_56_54_52_51.pdf),
- STM32 ARM processors have an [encoder mode](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/54/0f/67/eb/47/34/45/40/DM00042534.pdf/files/DM00042534.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00042534.pdf) that shares two timers
- AVR chips with two timers and a configurable logic unit can be set up to [efficiently read quadrature encoders](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/00002434A.pdf)
- Multiple NXP ARM processor families have a QEI: take a look at the [LPC17xx](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/brochure/75016846.pdf), [LPC18xx](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/brochure/75017637.pdf), and [LPC43xx](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/LPC4350_30_20_10.pdf) series